# Change date by timezone on knockout js databinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

I need a way to change dates of a field depending on timezones.
I am using knockout js and I looked through moment.js but I am not sure if moment.js will actually work.
But basically I have a code which does a data bind like this.

```
<td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: moment($data.duedate()).format('L')" ></span></td>
```

and I already put the js files on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/moment.js?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/moment-with-locales.js?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');?>"></script>
```

It says as a error that global variable moment is not declared so I am not sure what mistake I am doing. But then again my question is, is this moment js going to change depending on different time zone, if not, what can I do to make it change and is moment time zone js is the right one, and as well as how do I fix the databind.

Comment: From [this pull request](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/220), it sounds like momentjs is (as of just a month or so ago) now able to "guess" the users current timezone.  As you looking at knockout+javascript to do the timezone adjusting or were you hoping momentjs would do the adjustments for you based on (a) an arbitrary timezone selected by the user or (b) the users current timezone as reported by the browser?

Comment: @PatrickSteele the current timezone reported by browser

Comment: FYI - the time zone guessing feature is about being able to report the browser time zone as an IANA time zone identifier.  If you're just wanting conversion to the local time zone, you don't need to use that feature. You don't need moment-timezone at all, as moment.js works in the browser's local time zone by default.

Comment: Still, the question is quite unclear.  The only thing I can say for sure is that you should not load both moment  and moment-with-locales.  The moment-with-locales file already includes moment.